# VBA breaking while referencing a section in a formula within a loop

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am currently using a loop containing the following condition within a loop.

```
For Each Cell In Range("A3:A1000").Cells
     If Cell.Value = "Existing" And IsEmpty(Cell.Offset(0, 7).Value) Then
     Cell.Offset(0, 7).Value = "X"
     Cell.Offset(0, 5).Formula = "=VLookup(RC[-1],Customers!R2:T5000,2,FALSE)"
     Cell.Offset(0, 6).Formula = "=VLookup(RC[-2],Customers!R2:T5000,3,FALSE)"
     End If
Next Cell
```

Works well with one exception, whenever the formula is appended to a cell, the second value becomes CUSTOMERS!$2:$2:'T5000'.  Does anyone have any idea why this is occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed `.Formula` and `.FormulaR1C1` properties and correct syntax for each of these properties. Try with these lines:

```
Cell.Offset(0,5).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLookup(RC[-1],Customers!R2C18:R5000C20,2,FALSE)"
Cell.Offset(0,6).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLookup(RC[-2],Customers!R2C18:R5000C20,3,FALSE)"
```